# insert multiple strings at specific positions at once

Tags: php, substr

By `substr_replace`, I can insert a string in a specific index:

```
$a = 'abcdefg';
echo substr_replace($a, '1', 2, 0); // ab1cdefg
```

But, Is it possible to insert 2-3 strings at specific positions with just 1 `substr_replace`? (or other built-in functions)
for example:

```
$a = 'abcdefg';
$b = array('1', '2', '3');
$c = array(1, 2, 4);
echo substr_replace($a, $b, $c, 0); // a1b2cd3efg
```

I tried that code, but it returned an error:

> **Warning:** substr_replace() [function.substr-replace]: 'from' and 'len'
>   should be of same type - numerical or array

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now, first off, let me say that from reading the manual, I would have thought your code should work, you seem to be following the rules set out correctly.

What is even more ridiculous is that if you try and fix it by passing an array of `0`s to `$len` (sounds reasonable based on that error message, no?) [you get this](http://codepad.org/nzL5bIOX):

> **Warning**: substr_replace(): Functionality of 'from' and 'len' as arrays is not implemented

Right. So not only is the manual wrong, even the error messages contradict themselves. God I love PHP.

But enough of this, on to a solution...

---

Because it doesn't work as expected, you will have to loop in order to do what you want. Not too hard, right? Well, the major tripping hazard here is that *the length of the string and the offset positions will change on every iteration*. In order to stop this from causing a problem, you will need to perform the replacements *in reverse* so that the indexes are where you expect them to be.

Something like this:

```
<?php

  $a = 'abcdefg';
  $b = array('1', '2', '3');
  $c = array(1, 2, 4);

  for ($i = count($c) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $a = substr_replace($a, $b[$i], $c[$i], 0);
  }
  echo $a; // a1b2cd3efg
```

[See it working](http://codepad.org/pwQN4NAk)

Comment: The manual is not wrong. `replacement`, `from`, and `len` can only be arrays if `string` is also an array. In this case, it's just a convenient way to map `substr_replace` over all the corresponding sets of array elements. Note that your solution only works if `$c` is sorted.

Comment: As @Barmar said, `start` CANNOT be an array if the first parameter is an `string`. So before starting throwing the spells to PHP... RTFM xD. 
The example @kikio provided is an example of the functionality HE was expecting to get (and me too - in fact, that's what caused myself to reach this post).